# Content mismatch during Tridion Page Resolving

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We are facing a content mismatch issue during publishing multiple pages at a time.

Let's take two pages (A & B) with xml content. When I publish both pages together, the content of page A is replaced with the content of Page B but  Page B's content is correct. When we analyze the page content in the transportation package, it was already overwritten by the content of Page B.

We have checked pages.xml & instructions.xml files wherein we could see correct tcm id of the page and this is happening after deployer processed the page.

Environment details are 1 CME + 3 publishers (on different servers). We strongly believe that it must be something with page resolvers.

This issue is not occurring while publishing single page at a time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Extremely odd behavior, I wouldn't even know how to do that in a custom resolver... Why do you suspect a resolver?

Comment: Are both pages using the same templates? It seems like you may have some odd caching of a template output (but not sure that is possible) Can you try turning off to of the publishers, and report back if you see the same behavior? Also - please specify the version of Tridion you are using.

Comment: @NunoLinhares Coz while publishing 3 files at a time, 2nd page has 3rd page's content. When we checked the log file, I see 3rd page is processed first and then processing 2nd page. So I suspect, while resolving page content, page object might have been overwritten with its previous data.
Log:
1) Adding rendered item to the transport package: 3rd Page
2) Rendering of item [tcm:22-0002-64] '2ndPage' with template [tcm:22-21-128] 'PTName' in publication target
3) Adding rendered item to the transport package: 2ndPage

Comment: @ChrisSummers Yes, they are using same page templates and we have never set any caching on templating side. Also we have tried disabling one of the publisher server and published the pages again. Still no luch. We are using Hotfix Rollup SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - 1.

Comment: May I suggest taking this to SDL customer support? Stackoverflow is not a very good site for troubleshooting uncommon issues that don't involve code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, created SDL ticket also but just wanted to see if anyone has seen this issue before. Thanks Frank.

Comment: Do you have a custom deployer in place?

Comment: Another idea, do you use static variables in your template code?  Weird results are known to happen with this.

Comment: Never seen this behavior.. Strongly suggest check your templates code to see if any odd things going on.  Best way to test, publish using the Tridion OOTB Default templates which should work as expected assuming you did not override them.

Comment: I suspect you may have to go down the route of "test this on a server without any extensions". I have _never_ seen Tridion do anything like this.

Comment: I tend to agree with Nuno, if you suspect a resolver, then disable it and see if that fixes the issue, so you can narrow it down, and then perhaps add the resolver code to this question which is causing the issue?

Comment: Regarding @NickoliRoussakov 's comment maybe have a read of this http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/static-variables-in-tridion-templates

Comment: Yes, there are few static variables in the code which created this problem... identified by increasing threading level... Thanks everyone for your valuable comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into an issue where static variables within a template were producing garbage results, similar to what you're experiencing.  As per your last comment above, this seems to have solved your issue.  The details about why static variables shouldn't be used are explained here:  http://tridiondeveloper.com/static-variables-in-tridion-templates